ant fresh_install error/build failed Ubuntu 24.04
I've tried installing Dspace8 on Ubuntu 24.04 but I am stuck at the ant fresh_install. What could be the error and how would I fix it to run?
Below is what I receive when I run ant fresh_install in the cmd.
root@siltlibrary2-Veriton-Series:/build/DSpace-dspace-8.0/dspace/target/dspace-installer# ant fresh_install
Buildfile: /build/DSpace-dspace-8.0/dspace/target/dspace-installer/build.xml

init_installation:

prepare_configs:
\[mkdir\] Created dir: /build/DSpace-dspace-8.0/dspace/target/dspace-installer/config-temp
\[copy\] Copying 255 files to /build/DSpace-dspace-8.0/dspace/target/dspace-installer/config-temp
\[copy\] Copying 1 file to /build/DSpace-dspace-8.0/dspace/target/dspace-installer/config-temp
\[copy\] Copying 15 files to /build/DSpace-dspace-8.0/dspace/target/dspace-installer/config-temp

init_configs:
\[copy\] Copying 1 file to /dspace/config
\[delete\] Deleting directory /build/DSpace-dspace-8.0/dspace/target/dspace-installer/config-temp

test_database:
\[java\] 2024-11-19 11:01:02,198 ERROR org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseUtils @ Unable to setup Flyway against DSpace database
\[java\] java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:633) \~\[commons-dbcp2-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0\]
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:535) \~\[commons-dbcp2-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0\]
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:711) \~\[commons-dbcp2-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0\]
\[java\]    at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseUtils.setupFlyway(DatabaseUtils.java:594) \[dspace-api-8.0.jar:8.0\]
\[java\]    at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseUtils.main(DatabaseUtils.java:108) \[dspace-api-8.0.jar:8.0\]
\[java\]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) \~\[?:?\]
\[java\]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) \~\[?:?\]
\[java\]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) \~\[?:?\]
\[java\]    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569) \~\[?:?\]
\[java\]    at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.runOneCommand(ScriptLauncher.java:283) \[dspace-api-8.0.jar:8.0\]
\[java\]    at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.handleScript(ScriptLauncher.java:134) \[dspace-api-8.0.jar:8.0\]
\[java\]    at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:99) \[dspace-api-8.0.jar:8.0\]
\[java\] Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:346) \~\[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3\]
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) \~\[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3\]
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.\<init\>(PgConnection.java:273) \~\[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3\]
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:446) \~\[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3\]
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:298) \~\[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3\]
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:52) \~\[commons-dbcp2-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0\]
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:414) \~\[commons-dbcp2-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0\]
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:113) \~\[commons-dbcp2-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0\]
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:629) \~\[commons-dbcp2-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0\]
\[java\]    ... 11 more
\[java\] Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
\[java\]    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) \~\[?:?\]
\[java\]    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) \~\[?:?\]
\[java\]    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:547) \~\[?:?\]
\[java\]    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:602) \~\[?:?\]
\[java\]    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) \~\[?:?\]
\[java\]    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) \~\[?:?\]
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:243) \~\[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3\]
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.\<init\>(PGStream.java:98) \~\[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3\]
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136) \~\[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3\]
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262) \~\[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3\]
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) \~\[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3\]
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.\<init\>(PgConnection.java:273) \~\[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3\]
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:446) \~\[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3\]
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:298) \~\[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3\]
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:52) \~\[commons-dbcp2-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0\]
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:414) \~\[commons-dbcp2-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0\]
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:113) \~\[commons-dbcp2-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0\]
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:629) \~\[commons-dbcp2-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0\]
\[java\]    ... 11 more
\[java\] Caught exception:
\[java\] java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:633)
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:535)
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:711)
\[java\]    at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseUtils.main(DatabaseUtils.java:113)
\[java\]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
\[java\]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
\[java\]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
\[java\]    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
\[java\]    at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.runOneCommand(ScriptLauncher.java:283)
\[java\]    at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.handleScript(ScriptLauncher.java:134)
\[java\]    at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:99)
\[java\] Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:346)
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.\<init\>(PgConnection.java:273)
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:446)
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:298)
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:52)
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:414)
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:113)
\[java\]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:629)
\[java\]    ... 10 more
\[java\] Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
\[java\]    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
\[java\]    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
\[java\]    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:547)
\[java\]    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:602)
\[java\]    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
\[java\]    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:243)
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.\<init\>(PGStream.java:98)
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136)
\[java\]    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262)
\[java\]    ... 18 more

BUILD FAILED
/build/DSpace-dspace-8.0/dspace/target/dspace-installer/build.xml:783: Java returned: 1

Total time: 29 seconds
root@siltlibrary2-Veriton-Series:/build/DSpace-dspace-8.0/dspace/target/dspace-installer#


Ant is checking the database connection and if the postgresql extension pgcrypto is set up. The error message you posted shows that ant tries to connect to postgres on the computer you run ant (as localhost) and on port 5432. But, there is no database responding. Please check your database settings in dspace/config/local.cfg or if that does not exist in dspace/config/dspace.cfg. If you want to use a database on the same machine on which you are running ant, make sure it is properly installed, running and listening on localhost:5432.
